# Change the variable before saving Yii2 rest

Tags: rest, yii2

When adding an entry through the rest api how to change a variable before save values?

Below is a part of the controller code:

```
class RestusersController extends ActiveController
{
    public $modelClass = 'app\models\User';
    public function actions()
    {
        $actions = parent::actions();

        $actions['index']['prepareDataProvider'] = [$this, 'prepareDataProvider'];

        return $actions;
    }

    public function prepareDataProvider()
    {
        return new ActiveDataProvider([
            'query' => User::find()->where(['status_id'=>'1']),
            'pagination' => false,
        ]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

eg change the variable $ this-> status_id = 1;

```
public function beforeSave($insert)
{
    $this->status_id = 1;
    return parent::beforeSave($insert);
}
```